# Python Dictionary Binary Search Tree

Tags: python, dictionary, binary-tree

I am struggling to get to know how to code a basic implementation using a dictionary and in-order traversal binary search tree in Python. The class have to be using the below structure.

I would be very happy if someone could fill out the blanks (pass) in each function to get me started.

```
class Dictionary:

    def __init__ (self):

        pass

    def insert (self, key, value):

        pass

    def delete (self, key):

        pass

    def find (self, key):

        pass

    def traverse (self, f):

        pass

    def __str__ (self):

        return str(self)
```

Comment: I haven't understood what you're trying to do here. Are you trying to implement you're own dictionary class? Is this simply an academic excercise? I ask because python already has an excellent Dictionary implementation built into the language itself.

Comment: It smells like homework to me; just like you other question. If it is homework say so and we can point you in the direction of a good tutorial rather than telling you there is no point making your own versions of built in functionality.

Comment: There's definitely a point to having a binary tree data structure in Python and it's one of Python's missing pieces, but this is definitely homework.  Nobody who doesn't know how to implement a binary tree specifies an API like this, never mind saying that it *has* to use that API.

Answer (score 0):

> binary tree

You may want to use [the array representation of a binary tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree#Ahnentafel_list). Python has a powerful [list data type](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) which will make most of the work trivial. :)

```
class BinaryTree():
  def __init__(self):
     self.nodes = []
```

Here, that's a foundation you can start from.

Comment: Yes, I want to implement a dictionary class using a binary search tree.

Answer (score 0):

If you're still looking for an answer, have a look at this recipe: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577197-sortedcollection/.  I think it gives you enough of a basis to tweak it into exactly what you want.

Answer (score -2):

```
class Dictionary:
    def __init__ (self):
        self.data = {}
    def insert (self, key, value):
        self.data[key] = value
    def delete (self, key):
        if key in self.data:
            del self.data[key]
    def find (self, key):
        if key in self.data:
            return self.data[key]
        return None
    def traverse (self, f):
        for key,value in self.data:
            f(key,value)
    def __str__ (self):
        return str(self)
```

Comment: Endless recursion in `__str__`, missing `.items()` in `traverse`.

Comment: Isn't a binary tree; traversal is not "in-order" (OP didn't say what order he meant, but presumably sorted order, since that's what binary trees give you).  If you don't want to answer homework, I'm with you, but don't give deliberately bogus answers.  Python's dictionaries are not binary trees.

Comment: This is NOT a homework, I am not even a student, I am just trying to learn Python by myself on my spare time. Is there anyone that would be kind enough to help me out. What is wrong with the above code, what should it look like? Thankful for all help!